# Sentence with the same meaning as 'This box contains more than N balls,' when N is replaced by a phrase?

Tags: comparison

Sorry if this question is too easy.

When N is a number, like 6, we can simply say

> This box contains more than 6 balls.

Now, what if we replace '6' with a phrase like '**the number of rooms in my home**'?

Of course the sentence

> The number of balls in this box is greater than **the number of rooms in my home**.

is correct. But I'm looking for sentences beginning with 'This box contains'.

Comment: This box contains more balls than my home has rooms.

Comment: As StoneyB implies, if the phrase you substitute for ***N*** isn't (semantically and syntactically) equivalent to a ***number***, you have to move the head noun ***balls*** to before the comparator ***than***. You can do this when ***N*** is a number *(This box contains more balls than 6)*, but this is "unusual" phrasing for most contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'd like the phrase 'the number of rooms in my home' to be used.

Comment: It's your choice. You can say *This box contains more balls than the number of rooms in my home* if you want, but StoneyB's shorter version is far more natural and "elegant" from the native speaker's perspective. What you *can't* validly say is *This box contains **more than** the number of rooms in my home **balls***.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. The sentence I'm working on is: 'Only the computational cells containing more atoms than about 25% of the initial number of atoms per cell are considered for determining the limits of the colorbox.' The phrase 'containing more balls than the number of rooms in my home' has the structure 'containing more balls than N'. I've used the same structure. It seems odd while a phrase like 'containing more balls than wooden squares' sounds correct.

Comment: @Arham: The context *more balls than wooden squares* is one where the "comparand" (the thing/amount being used to make the comparison, ***wooden squares*** in this case) is NOT "a number" (so you can't say *It contains more than wooden squares balls*). In your "atoms" example I suggest you remove the first instance of that word. It's not actually ungrammatical to include it, but it's clumsy phrasing to have it twice. Alternatively, remove the *second* occurrence: *Only [the] computational cells containing more atoms than about 25% of the initial number per cell are [blah blah].*